# AWS Cognito does not use my custom message lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-cognito

I have created an AWS Cognito User Pool through Terraform as follow:

```
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "users-base" {
  name     = "users"
  provider = aws.eu-west-1

  auto_verified_attributes   = ["email"]
  username_attributes        = ["email"]

  account_recovery_setting {
    recovery_mechanism {
      name     = "verified_email"
      priority = 1
    }
    recovery_mechanism {
      name     = "verified_phone_number"
      priority = 2
    }
  }

  admin_create_user_config {
    allow_admin_create_user_only = false
  }

  email_configuration {
    email_sending_account = "DEVELOPER"
    from_email_address    = "No-reply <no-reply@acme.com>"
    source_arn            = aws_ses_email_identity.no-reply.arn
  }

  lambda_config {
    custom_message = aws_lambda_function.cognito-users-base.arn
  }
}
```

While I expect that my users receive mails generated from `aws_lambda_function.cognito-users-base` (which is configured correctly, since it was generating errors previously), they still receive messages generated according to `verification_message_template.email_message_by_link`, what do I miss?

Edit: I also have checked that the generated smsMessage has less than 140 caracters, and the emailMessage less than 20.000. Moreover, when I add an attribute, the SignUp process blocks, so the lambda is called, one way of another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like my lambda was generating a body without `{##Some text##}` in it, leading to a silent discard of the generated body.